# changing the default log rotate config for kerberos

Tags: kerberos, logrotate

I notice that the default kerberos configuration to rotate the log files is monthly. I don't find any option to control this through the Kerberos config file - `krb5.conf`. If the configuration needs to be changed to, say, daily, do I need to overwrite the entries in `/etc/logrotate.d/kadmind` and `/etc/logrotate.d/krb5kdc`?

```
<Log Dir>/krb5kdc.log {
    missingok
    notifempty
    monthly
    rotate 12
    postrotate
        /bin/kill -HUP `cat /var/run/krb5kdc.pid 2>/dev/null` 2> /dev/null || true
    endscript
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One day, I found one of our Kerberos servers was out of space. I found Kerberos does not handle logs rotate by default. That’s why it ate a lot of space. So, here is the way to make Kerberos logs rotate.

Editing /etc/logrotate.d/krb5kdc file `vi /etc/logrotate.d/krb5kdc`

```
/var/log/krb5kdc.log {
    missingok
    notifempty
    create 0640 root root
    postrotate
        /etc/init.d/krb5kdc condrestart >/dev/null 2>&1 || true
    endscript
}
```

And editing /etc/logrotate.d/kadmin file

```
/var/log/kadmind.log {
    missingok
    notifempty
    create 0640 root root
    postrotate
        /etc/init.d/kadmin condrestart >/dev/null 2>&1 || true
    endscript
}
```

After you edited these two files, it will do the logs rotate by itself, weekly. If you would like to test logs rotate, you can use following command :
`logrotate -f -v /etc/logrotate.conf`